# In vimscript, is there any events triggered by the internal commands?

Tags: vim

for example,
in command mode, if I type ":cd /Home"
A events can be triggered by the cd command and I can get the path of the destination directory (/Home) of the command.

something like: 
autocmd cd * : echo "blabla"

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not. You'll find the entire event list at `:help autocmd-events`. I see the following options:

- If it's just the `:cd` command, you could create an override `:Cd` command that triggers your additional functionality after delegating to the original `:cd`. To avoid having to type the uppercase `:Cd`, you can use [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746). I would prefer this approach.
- Though there's no hook for Ex commands, you could intercept all interactively entered commands by hooking into `:cmap <CR>` and using `getcmdline()`, but that requires parsing by yourself and the global hook doesn't play well with other plugins / configurations.
- As the effects of  `:cd` can be observed with `getcwd()`, you could hook into other regular events such as `CursorHold,CursorMoved`, if you live with a small delay.